# React-Native parsing xml using fast-xml-parser

Tags: php, xml, react-native

i'm getting this Error

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: (0, _fastXmlParser.parse) is not a function. (In '(0, _fastXmlParser.parse)(data)', '(0, _fastXmlParser.parse)' is undefined)]

When using [fast-xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser/v/3.20.0) package, what I'm trying is to parse this XML and logging it in the console, this is the code so far:-

```
import { parse } from 'fast-xml-parser';

function test(){
  const emp_number = 20209;
  fetch('http://website.com/partner/api.php?emp_number='+`${emp_number}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  }
})
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((data) => {
            let obj = parse(data);
            let servicenumber = obj.counter.serviceNumber;
            let consumpationtype = obj.counter.consumpationtype;
            let currentread = obj.counter.currentread;
            let currentdate = obj.counter.currentdate;
            let lastread = obj.counter.lastread;
            let lastdate = obj.counter.lastdate;
            let consumpation = obj.counter.consumpation;
            console.log("CurrentReading:"+`${currentread}`);
});}
```

and this is api.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $gecolEmployee = $_GET['emp_number'];

    $serverName = "host\SqlS"; 
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"gecol");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM readers WHERE emp_number=?";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array($gecolEmployee));
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
        if( $conn ) {
            echo $row['xml'];
        }else{
            echo "خطأ.<br />";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
?>
```

and the xml response

```
<counter>
    <serviceNumber>200135644</serviceNumber>
    <consumpationtype>1</consumpationtype>
    <currentread>95808</currentread>
    <currentdate>29/6/2022</currentdate>
    <lastread>85808</lastread>
    <lastdate>29/5/2022</lastdate>
    <consumpation>?</consumpation>
    <counternumber>7038842</counternumber>
    <phonenumber>0928065968</phonenumber>
</counter>
```

Comment: Should it be `parser.parse(data)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was having the same problem in react native with the lastest version of fast-xml-parser. I've found that older versions just work fine.

- uninstall your current version: npm uninstall fast-xml-parser
- install this version: npm i fast-xml-parser@3.12.13

Then, import the method and use it, it worked for me following this steps:

import {parse} from "fast-xml-parser"

const resExampleXML = `YOUR XML DATA`

const parsedData = parse(resExampleXML)

console.warn(parsedData)